# Automate Opening a file that is down loaded from a site or file explorer

Tags: excel, download, power-automate, powerapps

I have a created a PA Flow that launches a browser, goes to a particular site, select particular items from the site, then download and exports the search results via an excel file. I am running into an issue in getting the downloaded excel file to open. Any Assistance on whether this can be done without having to create a dedicated folder that the down-loaded file gets saved to?

In Past flows where I used the recorder, it open based on the date. Since the date is not static, looking into a more dynamic option so flow run as date changes.

[image: Download from the Web]
[image: Download from File Explorer]